# scala enumeration race condition

Tags: scala, enumeration

```
object Test extends App {
  val env = Envi.withName("YY")
  println(env)
}


object Envi extends Enumeration {
  val YY, XX = Value
  val currentEnvironment: Envi.Value = YY
}
```

Interesting that sometimes when you run it you get expected result (YY), sometimes it fails with exception because YY mapped to currentEnvironment.

scala version: 2.12.8

Anyone knows why it works so strange?

Note: if you change to `private val currentEnvironment: Envi.Value = YY` - no exception is thrown